# How to get Ruby generated HMAC for SHA256 that is url safe to match Java?

Tags: java, ruby, sha256, hmac

I have a tomcat server running some Java code that lets users authenticate using an API key.  The request uses an HMAC created with SHA256.  I have a Ruby client that I am using to make the request and since I'm new to encryption I am having a difficult time getting it to generate a matching HMAC.  I have tried not making it URL safe, and that matches.  So I'm really wondering is how I can get the Ruby client to match with the URL safe version (since I can't change the Java code).  It's just got an extra = character at the end.  Thanks in advance for any help.

For Ruby I am using 1.9.3 and for Java I am using 6u31 along with the commons-codec-1.6.jar library from apache.

**Code**

Ruby:

```
require "openssl"
require "base64"

json_str = "{'community':'LG7B734A', 'login_id':'user1', 'time':'1331928899'}"
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new("sha256")
key = [ "4cc45e4258121c3fec84147673e1bd88e51b1c177aafcfa2da72bd4655c9f933" ]
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, key.pack("H*"), json_str)

encoded_url_safe = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(hmac)
encoded = Base64.encode64(hmac)

puts("Encoded (Url Safe): " + encoded_url_safe)
puts("Encoded           : " + encoded)
```

Java:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Mac;

public class ExampleHMAC
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String key = "4cc45e4258121c3fec84147673e1bd88e51b1c177aafcfa2da72bd4655c9f933";
        byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());

        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(keySpec);

        String jsonStr = "{'community':'LG7B734A', 'login_id':'user1', 'time':'1331928899'}";
        byte[] hmacBytes = mac.doFinal(jsonStr.getBytes());

        String encodedUrlSafe = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(hmacBytes);
        String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(hmacBytes);

        System.out.println("Encoded (Url Safe): " + encodedUrlSafe);
        System.out.println("Encoded           : " + encoded);
    }
}
```

**Output**

Ruby:

```
Encoded (Url Safe): QgYLqGm1M4qozdEjGC_CnJ8CdBm2jQpsU85kSWFcjKM=
Encoded           : QgYLqGm1M4qozdEjGC/CnJ8CdBm2jQpsU85kSWFcjKM=
```

Java:

```
Encoded (Url Safe): QgYLqGm1M4qozdEjGC_CnJ8CdBm2jQpsU85kSWFcjKM
Encoded           : QgYLqGm1M4qozdEjGC/CnJ8CdBm2jQpsU85kSWFcjKM=
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby does not remove the trailing '=' - it is not an absolute requirement, as you can read in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) it just states that removing them might be desirable in certain applications. But other than that it is guaranteed that Ruby's URL-safe encoding will be exactly the same as Java's.

So the only thing for you to do is strip off the trailing '==', you could for example use a regex:

```
encoded_url_safe_.gsub!(/=+$/, "")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  The reference to RFC 4648 was very helpful and thorough.  I didn't know the trailing '=' was optional.  I added that regex code and it works.  Thank you.