# hexdigest equivalent in android

Tags: java, android, python, django

I have implemented HMAC to hash the password in python as below

```
SECRET_KEY='SOME_KEY'     
digest = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY,str(bundle.data['password']), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this exactly on Android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9744392/967142

Comment: See this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11102291/1008278